# JavaScript Function Call explained keeps returning null

Tags: javascript, ajax, function, call

I have a code that will run, collects the data (ajax library) and then I need to get so that the user can then add it's own function to the library and run it. Sort of like `$.get` Hard to explain what I mean.

**EXAMPLE**

```
 _$.ajax({
    url:"url",
    cache:false,
    done:function(data){
     console.log(data);
    }
 });
```

Though I am not sure how to make sure that data equals `ajax.response` which is technically the collection of `XMLHttpRequest.responseText;`

I've tried doing this inside my code

```
 var ajax = {
   response:null,
   fnDone:null,
   done:function(fn){
     return ajax.done.call(fn);
   },
   init:function(){ //js to start xml
   ajax.process();
   },
   process:function(){ // js to finish XML 
     ajax.done(ajax.fnDone);
   }
   ajax:function(opts){
     ajax.fnDone = opts.done;
    }
   }
```

It's just not working? Can someone better explain the arguments that call is going for?

**UPDATE**

I need to understand how to get arguments to be a predefined variable.

**EX:**

```
 _$.ajax({
    url:"url",
    cache:false
    }).done(
```

`function(`**data**`){ console.log(data); });`

While **data** or whatever they want as the arguments name is predefined to be `ajax.response`

Comment: Are you using jQuery? Did you check the docs: http://api.jquery.com/get/ ?

Comment: I'm not using jquery I am writing my own library I was trying to update my question with more information. My mind is mush right now trying to figure this out :D sorry

Answer (score 0):

`.call` expects `this` to be the first argument, and then each of the function's arguments, in order, after that.

```
var Bob = { name : "Bob" },
    sayName = function (greeting) { console.log(greeting + " " + this.name + "!"); };


sayName.call(Bob, "Hi, I'm"); // "Hi, I'm Bob!"
```

If you pass in `null` or `undefined` as the first argument, `this` inside the function will be `window`.

```
var name = "Steve";
sayName.call(Bob, "I'm");  // I'm Bob!
sayName.call(null, "I'm"); // I'm Steve!
```

Of course, ideally, to avoid that sort of hair, your functions should either be written/called with specific objects in mind, or you should avoid using `this` inside of the functions.
There is a time and place for both.

Comment: Ok from what you've told me I'll take another shot at it

Comment: Ok so it's not doing exactly what I need still. I want the arguments to be the responseText of the xhr.responseText so that they can manipulate and use this later.